# Issue in transition of Conditional rendering in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using this modal to add/update an user's information. I have four buttons in footer: 'Close', 'Deactivate User', 'Reset Password' and 'Save Changes'.

Deactivate User and Reset Password buttons do not appear when creating new users. They appear for existing users.

The code works well for me. For true state of addUser, I display other two buttons in footer. For false state of addUser (i.e while updating existing users), I display all four buttons.

When I close the modal, I change the state of showModal to false which hides the modal.

But during the transition for a split second, I can see the buttons which would otherwise be visible only for false state.

How can I prevent the display of other buttons 'Deactivate User' and 'Reset Password' when the modal is about to close?

```
modal = () => {
        const { FirstName, LastName, Email, PhoneNumber, Type, showModal, addUser } = this.state;
        const title = FirstName && LastName ? `${ LastName }, ${ FirstName }` : Email;
        return (
        <Modal show={showModal} onHide={this.close}>
            <Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Title>{title}</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>

            <Modal.Body>
                <Input inputValue={FirstName || ''} inputLabel="First Name" id="FirstName" handleChange={this.handleChange}/>
                <Input inputValue={LastName || ''} inputLabel="Last Name" id="LastName" handleChange={this.handleChange}/>
                <Input inputValue={Email} inputLabel="Email" id="Email" disabled={!this.state.addUser} validationSate={this.state.EmailErrorState} errorMessage={this.state.EmailErrorMessage} handleChange={this.handleChange}/>
                <Input inputValue={this.formatPhone(PhoneNumber)} inputLabel="Phone Number" id="PhoneNumber" handleChange={this.handleChange}/>
                <Dropdown selectedOption={Type} dropdownLabel="Type" id="Type" dropdownOptions={this.typeOptions} handleChange={this.handleDropdownChange}/>
            </Modal.Body>

            {this.getFooter()}
        </Modal>
    );
}

getFooter = () => {
    if (this.state.addUser) {
        return (
            <Modal.Footer>
                <Button onClick={this.close}>Close</Button>
                <Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={this.updateUser} disabled={this.state.disableSave}>Save changes</Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <Modal.Footer>
                <Button onClick={this.close}>Close</Button>
                <Button onClick={this.deactivateUser}>Deactivate User</Button>
                <Button bsStyle="danger" onClick={this.resetPassword}>Reset Password</Button>
                <Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={this.updateUser} disabled={this.state.disableSave}>Save changes</Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
        );
    }
}

close = () => {
    this.setState(previousState => ({ ...this.blankState }));
}
```

The blank state is as below:

```
blankState = {
    Email: '',
    FirstName: '',
    LastName: '',
    PhoneNumber: '',
    Type: '',
    showModal: false,
    addUser: false,
    disableSave: true
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using a single boolean variable to represent more than 2 states.

State A

> For true state of addUser, I display other two buttons in footer.

State B

> For false state of addUser (i.e while updating existing users), I display all four buttons.

State C

> I change the state of addUser to false which hides the modal.

It seems that your using `addUser` to represent both the button rendering as well as the general modal rendering.

If you split these two concerns into two separate variables, one to represent whether to show multiple buttons and one to represent whether or not the modal is showing, then you will no longer see the split-second flash, since the logic is no longer shared.

Comment: I have updated the code. I was using showModal to show/hide the modal. addUser is used to know whether it's a add action or else edit User action

Answer (score 0):

You said 'I change the state of addUser to false which hides the modal.'

but your modal

`<Modal show={showModal} onHide={this.close}>`

has `showModal` property and `onHide` method, change `showModal` to false in `onHide` method is the right way to hide modal.

Comment: @ Z blast: Yes you are correct. I have updated the code and information in the question

Comment: Where is the `blankState`, you can't get the `blankState` by this. You can pass it to the `setState` directly, or put it in the `close()`.

Comment: All the code is in a class UserManagement which extends React.PureComponent so I am able to use this.blankState.